# Threading or multiprocessing? Returns a very large array

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multithreading

Newbie here in multiprocessing. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def func():
    with mp.Pool(initializer = init, initargs = [a,b]) as p:
        temp_arr = p.starmap(process, tuple_list)
        #p.close(); p.join() #Seems Pool will take care of this

    arr = [sum(x) for x in zip(*temp_arr)]
```

tuple_list has millions of tuples and is the reason for my trying of multiprocessing here. In my understanding, this is a cpu-bound task (faster cpu makes this computation faster) rather than an I/O-bound, so I am going with multiprocessing. Please correct me I am not right.

```
def init (tempa, tempb):
    global a,b
    a = tempa
    b = tempb
```

The init() seems to create extra over-head. My actual code has more variables and two arrays to be passed for init. Can it be done better?

```
def process(a1, a2):
    arr = np.zeros(some N)
    #Using a, b, a1, a2 here and 'arr' (very large) is modified
    return arr
```

The problem is the size of 'arr' is rather large and each process needs to have its own arr. Is there an efficient way of handling this using multi-processing? E.g., is it possible to initialize the arr in func() and access this directly by each process()? Of course, race-condition needs to be taken care of here. Or any alternatives, please?

Also, is multi-threading is good here? Again, I can create the  arr in func() and this should be accessible to all threads but I don't know how much speed-up I can get using threading and am even less familiar in implementing threading.

Edit:

```
def compute_gaussian_str_func_one_particle(Natoms, particle_types, cell_list, num_classes = 2, rmax=5.0, sigma=0.1):
    neighbs  = cell_list.query (cell_list.points, dict(mode = "ball", r_max = rmax, r_min = 0.01))
    radii = np.arange(0.0, rmax, sigma)
    global output
    output = np.zeros(num_classes*len(radii)*Natoms)

    with mp.Pool(initializer=init_pool, initargs=[num_classes,radii,sigma,particle_types,Natoms]) as p:
        a=p.starmap(process, neighbs) 
        p.close()
        p.join()

    output=[sum(x) for x in zip(*a)]
    return output
    
def process(a1,a2,a3):
    neighb_type = particle_types[a2]
    dist = a3
    c=a1*num_classes*len(radii)
    output[c+neighb_type * len(radii) : c+(neighb_type+1) * len(radii)] += np.exp(- (dist - radii)**2 / (2*sigma**2))
    return output

def init_pool(a,b,c,d,e):
    global num_classes,radii,sigma,particle_types,Natoms
    num_classes = a
    radii = b
    sigma = c
    particle_types = d
    Natoms = e
```

Comment: If you're running this on an UNIX system (e.g. Linux, macOS) and `Pool` is backed by forking, then yes, you could pre-load your data into a (global) variable that's accessible by the `process` function, and it will be efficiently shared, but down only - not back up to the parent process! On Windows, you're out of luck on that front.

Comment: @AKX Thank you! Was not aware of this. I tried "global arr" and "arr = np.zeros(some N)" in func() in order to work on this from process(). However, when I checked the value of 'arr' in process(), sometimes it's not all zeroes. A few elements are getting corrupted by the 'arr' returned from other processes. Including p.close() and p.join() also did not help. Can you see why this is the case?

Comment: Assuming you really are using a process pool, there should be no way that changes from subprocesses can propagate up to the parent process. Can you post the code you actually tried?

Comment: @AKX I agree, since that is the core behavior.. I must be doing something wrong.. Please see the code inserted into my question now

Comment: If `init_pool` is the `initializer` you pass to `mp.Pool()`, it's being run in all children separately, which is not what you want. You'd want to call that in the parent, then start forking children, to take advantage of copy-on-write. (Sorry I can't help more right now, gotta afk.)

Comment: @AKX if possible, could you explain more on what you meant above? I don't fully understand it

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood your original code, it looks like. I was under the impression you had some precalculated data you wanted to share between subprocesses, but you seem to be attempting to assign into a slice of would-be shared data. You _may_ be able to do that with `multiprocessing.Array`s (which are shared memory), but it would be easier to just return the slices (possibly with indices) and do the summing/manipulation in the parent process.